# Can I tell the CLR to marshal immutable objects between AppDomains by reference?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, remoting, appdomain

When marshaling objects between AppDomains in .NET the CLR will either serialize the object (if it has the `Serializable` attribute) or it will generate a proxy (if it inherits from `MarshalByRef`)

With strings however the CLR will just pass the reference to the string object into the new AppDomain. The CLR still ensures integrity since .NET strings are immutable and any change by the second AppDomain to the string will not effect the original object.

Which brings me to my question: is there a way to tell the CLR that my custom type is immutable and when used in remoting it should just pass the reference to the object as it does with the string class?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but does it pin the string before it lets it cross the boundary?

Comment: If by pin you mean like a fixed {} block, then no, pinning is only used when sending object references into unmanaged territory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marshalling is actually [fairly tricky](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/06/01/51466.aspx).

The behaviour you are describing is called "marshal-by-bleed", the runtime uses it to marshal strings (sometimes) and marshal System.Threading.Thread ALWAYS.

As far as I can tell you have no control over this (its mentioned in the article that you can define custom marshalling behaviour but I can not find any documentation on it), you could potentially pass an IntPtr around and use unsafe code to simulate this, but it smells like a huge hack to me.

Comment: big +1 for the link, Marshall by Bleed is interesting

Comment: You can implement custom marshal-by-bleed with a bit of trickery: https://bitbucket.org/kgtinv/kgtpublic_utils/src/49ec9be278a7cff65838a42069eeef85f248a9ad/src/Kreslik.Integrator.LowLatencyUtils/CrossAppDomainData.cs#lines-17

Comment: Quick description: make one AppDomain ('master') own the data, then form other app domains ('slaves') call into that, let it give you the memory address and in the destination domain wrap it into full blown GC object. You have to control that no GC occured during this process (which is quite quick and you can retry otherwise) and you should prevent GC collecting of this wrapper in 'slave' AppDomains

Comment: Jan's link is dead. Here's another article explaining how to achieve marshal by bleed. http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/07/25/150301.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, no. I believe that this, like the primitives, is handled directly by the runtime.

Comment: This is wrong, as described here: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/07/25/150301.aspx

Comment: @Robert I'm happy to stand corrected. I'm even happier to say that since app-domains are now obsolete (.net core, etc) it is moot :)

Comment: Well, a few of us are still needing to dabble with .NET Framework for years to come. Digging up ancient knowledge from SO and defunct blogs is becoming a forensics art form 

Answer (score -1):

You only have two marshaling semantics in .NET Remoting: marshal by value (SerializableAttribute) and marshal by reference (MarshalByRef).

As you alluded to, strings are marshaled by value, as System.String is decorated with the SerializableAttribute.

If you want to pass your object between app domains and you want just a copy (no changes in on the object in the remote app domain affect the object in the local app domain) then what you want is to use the SerializableAttribute on your class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry sambo99's linked blog indicates that you are wrong, you might want to update

Comment: The third option is to load domain neutral assemblies: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/07/25/150301.aspx